# C# UWP BackgroundMediaPlayer no sound after store association

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I developed a UWP music app in C# which use BackgroundMediaPlayer in Windows API.
**Since I associated the app to the store**, it doesn't play sound after the first app launch.

- 1st launch -> Everything is fine.
- x launch after until computer restart => **No sound** (still playback
  position tracking/play/pause works).

Does somebody have an explanation or a fix?

Comment: I have the exact same problem I used the examples from Microsoft. My app is now live and it is broken after the second launch. I posted a ticket on github https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer from a Microsoft employee:

> We have confirmed the root cause and we are getting this fixed. Sorry about that. The workaround is to change your "Package name" to be greater than 20 characters. Please let us know if that works for you.

When I associated my app with the store, my package name got under 20 character; wich was causing the bug.
I changed it to be more than 20 char and my app worked well again.

The problem is that any store association or app upload will set back the package name.

Microsoft told me the bug will be fixed. It was on October 1th 2015.
Check https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/141 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen, this is some bug introduced in Windows 10 RTM. At this point I would advise you to use alternative APIs (like MediaElement).